# Can't resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, terminal, program-entry-point, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to run a simple java program with terminal:

```
   public class Test
   {
       public static void main(String...args)
       {
           System.out.println("Hello World");
       }
   }
```

So i compile using this command: `javac Test.java` and this produces the binary file `Test.class`.
When I try to run the program with `java Test` I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
```

I don't know what to do anymore.
When I run `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get the correct path:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I also tried to run using `java -cp /path-to-Test.class Test` and `java .cp . Test` but those also didn't work.

The program is not in a package.
The program is in the desktop folder in macOS.
What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Is `Test` really in the default package?

Comment: And is `Test.class` in the directory you try to execute `java Test`?

Comment: java -cp ... is the right approach. But the path should only include directories, not the file name.

Comment: And is Test.class in the directory you try to execute java Test? Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

When you write "Test" use the whole package path.

like:

```
java com.some.dir.Test
```

for using  with -cp:
if you executing from Test location, you can use

```
java -cp . Test
```

else - you should mention the path

```
java -cp . com.some.dir.Test
```

Comment: I also tried 'java -cp . Test' but this didn't work too

Comment: @alessandro.zinni, yes but you didnt add the package path so it doesn't work.
did you try to run the command from same location of Test file ?